# Matrix values increasing after SVD, singular value decomposition

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd, image-processing

I am trying to learn SVD for image processing... like compression.

My approach: get image as BufferedImage using ImageIO... get RGB values and use them to get the equivalent grayscale value (which lies within 0-255) and store it in a double[][] array. And use that array in SVD to compress it.

I am getting my USV matrices correctly... hope so. I get from U from AATranspose (AAT), and V from ATA.

Let me give an example

A is my original matrix.

```
A = 7.0     3.0     2.0
    9.0     7.0     5.0
    9.0     8.0     7.0
    5.0     3.0     6.0

U = -0.34598    -0.65267    -0.59969    -0.30771
    -0.57482    -0.27634     0.26045     0.72484
    -0.64327     0.21214     0.44200    -0.58808
    -0.36889     0.67280    -0.61415     0.18463

S = 21.57942    0.00000    0.00000
     0.00000    3.35324    0.00000
     0.00000    0.00000    2.02097
     0.00000    0.00000    0.00000

VT = -0.70573    -0.52432    -0.47649
     -0.53158    -0.05275     0.84536
     -0.46838     0.84989    -0.24149
```

So now I have to do outer product expansion, leaving out a few terms for compression. Lets call the truncated terms k.

When I let k = 1, and do outer product expansion with the singular values, this is what I get as my new matrix

```
B = 6.43235    4.03003    1.70732
    9.24653    6.55266    5.12711
    9.41838    7.24083    7.21571
    4.41866    4.05485    5.70027
```

As you can see, some values in B (which I think should be my final matrix after SVD) are greater than my original matrix.

`A` is just a test matrix. I would later try to compress a grayscale image, and there the values have to be 0-255. Anything > 255 wouldn't help me.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is it only the fact that some values are larger that makes you think that you are doing something wrong?

Comment: @Calle... to be honest, yes. This is the first time I am doing this. I would be using this to compress an image which has R G B components in 0-255. Even a single component > 255 would fail the compressed image creation.

Answer (score 2):

You raise an interesting point. The ultimate solution is to use thresholding to clear up this malady; the SVD is working as designed.

An example follows. Start with $\mathbf{A}$, a picture (here Camille Jordan), and perform a low rank approximation up through the first 4 singular values. (A final plot shows the quality with the first 30 singular values.)

The input picture was adjusted so that the values are bound within the interval $[0,1]$. The table below shows how the extrema drift with each approximation. The graphics tools clipped the values to maintain the interval $[0,1]$.

```
k    Min    Max
1    0.258  1.107
2   -0.008  1.092
3    0.008  1.120
4   -0.034  1.109
```

[image: Low rank 1]
[image: Low rank 2]
[image: Low rank 3]
[image: Low rank 4]

---

[image: Low rank 30]